# Session Initiation Protocol

Tags: networking, sip

Does SIP v2.0 permit to have the protocol running over non-standard ports 
(not 5060)? I've checked through the specification, but wasn't able to find 
an answer. It looks like a port can be negotiated and determined during a 
registration phase, but I could not confirm this with RFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, port 5060/5061 are just the *default* ports if no other port is given. [RFC3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261) also only gives listening to port 5060/5061 as a recommendation;

> It is also RECOMMENDED that a server
> listen for requests on the default SIP ports (5060 for TCP and UDP,
> 5061 for TLS over TCP) on all public interfaces.

For example, if you use DNS lookup according to [RFC3263](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3263), the port is looked up at the same time as the address;

```
That lookup would return:  
  
;;          Priority Weight Port   Target  
    IN SRV  0        1      5060   server1.example.com  
    IN SRV  0        2      5060   server2.example.com
```

Comment: Joachim Isaksson, thank you for your answer. I wonder are there any requirements for minimum size of a SIP message?

Answer (score 0):

Well Yes you can use the other ports for sending Sip packets... Port Forwarding is a Hint...